# Need drag-bar to overflow and fit full width of div?

Tags: css

I have a drag bar that allows me to resize a div. The problem is there is content in the div that overflows the div in the x-direction and when I scroll over, the drag bar disappears since it's width is 100% of the div and does not overflow. How would I get it to overflow with the rest of the content so even when I scroll over, the drag bar is still visible?

Picture of what I'm talking about. The orange bar is the drag-bar and it disappears at a certain point when I scroll in the x-direction to view content.
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="attribute-table">
    <button id="selectPatches">Select Patches</button>
    <button id="clearSelection">Clear Selection</button>
    <span id="featureCount">No features selected</span>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Point</th>
                <th>Patch Number</th>
                <th>Is Developed?</th>
                <th>Crop Type</th>
                <th>Crop Residue (%)</th>
                <th>Canopy Over 12' (%)</th>
                <th>Deciduous Canopy (%)</th>
                <th>Coniferous Canopy (%)</th>
                <th>Shrub Cover (%)</th>
                <th>Shrub Stem Density (%)</th>
                <th>Grass Cover (%)</th>
                <th>Forb Cover (%)</th>
                <th>Forb Protective Cover (%)</th>
                <th># of Forb Species</th>
                <th>Bare Ground (%)</th>
                <th>Herbaceous Height > 8"</th>
                <th>Coarse Habitat Type</th>
                <th>Fine Habitat Type</th>
                <th>Quail Habitat</th>
                <th>Observation Date</th>
                <th>Observation Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-data">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="attrTable-handle" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#attribute-table {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 250px;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    top: auto !important;
    padding-top: 7px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 31;
    overflow: auto;
}
#attrTable-handle {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
//Allow attribute table to be resized
$("#attribute-table").resizable({
    handles: {
        'n': '#attrTable-handle'
    }
});
```

Comment: Make it wider than `width:100%`.

Comment: Your source doesn't show anything. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/2x764bwc/

Answer (score 0):

Because the width of this div can be changed by the user by collapsing another div, I had to set the width of the drag-bar dynamically. I did this by finding the scrollWidth of the div and then set the drag-bar width to it with the css() method.

```
//Set the width of the drag-bar based on the content width
var width = $("#attribute-table")[0].scrollWidth;
$("#attrTable-handle").css("width", width);
```